# How to install and start the 0.4-pre Julia kernel with IPython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I installed the 0.4-pre Julia kernel on a mac, which goes into

```
/Applications/Julia-0.4.0-pre-349a4e1977.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia
```

and set the symbolic link to this kernel

```
ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.4.0-pre-349a4e1977.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

but in my IPython notebook, aka Jupiter, the 0.3.10 starts up when

```
ipython notebook --profile=julia
```

How to include the 0.4-pre kernel option in the IPython notebook?

Answer (score 3):

If you have IPython/Jupyter version 3 or above, then you should start it with

```
ipython notebook
```

without the

```
--profile julia
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `Pkg.add("IPython")` and `Pkg.build("IPython")` in 0.4 to add the 0.4 kernel spec to Jupyter.  This is similar to the instructions for when you update Julia [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#updating-julia-and-ijulia).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Using the info from @ARM and @David P. Sanders, what eventually worked for me on a mac was:

1. Run the downloaded julia 0.4-pre in a Terminal: `exec '/Applications/Julia-0.4.0-pre-349a4e1977.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'`, which gives me a Julia prompt.
2. At this Julia prompt run `Pkg.add("IJulia")`, which creates a ~/.julia/v0.4 directory and installs `IJulia` and a few other packages in that directory.
3. `quit()` from this julia prompt.
4. Navigate to the directory in the Terminal where your `myNotebook.ipynb`'s are or where you want to create them and run `ipython notebook` at the Terminal prompt, which should open a webpage on `localhost:8888` with that directory's files listed. Click on the file you want edit.